# curl error,troubleshoot json/php error

Tags: php, json, curl

cURL Error (28): Operation timed out after 201 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Here is my code:

```
if (!isset($_GET['foo'])) {
// Client   
$pIds = array("All");
$data = array("apiToken" => "apitoken-3D", "productIds" => $pIds); 
$data_string = json_encode($data); 
//echo $data_string;
$ch = curl_init('http://myurl/WriteProductData'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 
'Content-Type: application/json', 
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)) 
); 
$data = curl_exec($ch);
//var_dump(json_decode($data, true));
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);    
if ($curl_errno > 0) {
echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n"; 
} else {
echo "Data received: $data\n";

} else {
// Server
sleep(10);
echo "Done.";
}
```

Above is not the real API key, etc. but just wanted you to see the code.

Please advise how to troubleshoot this, and what to do to resolve this issue. We can make adjustments on the server if necessary.

Comment: Does it work without the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200);` line?  Also, I'm not sure you need the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);` line.

Comment: Errno 28 is a timeout -- meaning it can't connect to that URL.  Is it able to revole your URL by name?  Is it listening on port 80?  Do you get a response on an HTTP POST to that URL on port 80?